# RegEx - extend a given string while leaving the rest untouched

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an associate array inside a PHP class method going like this:

```
// ...

$filters = [
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_BETWEEN => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_GREATER => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_GREATER_OR_EQUAL => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_LESS => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
    self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_LESS_OR_EQUAL => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
];

// ...
```

What I would like to do is to convert this string from:

```
self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_BETWEEN => "Base/*/Creation/Date.php",
```

to this one:

```
self::FILTER_CREATION_DATE_BETWEEN => "Base/*/Creation/Date/Between.php",
```

I would like to use a RegEx to extend the string but leave the rest untouched. I need to do this because there's more than 120 constants defined ending with `*_BETWEEN`.

How can I do this?

Comment: So, you want to modify all values in the array that have an index which is a class constant whose name ends in `BETWEEN` to have `Between.php` instead of `Date.php`?

Comment: @Nick to be Date/Between.php rather than Between.php. I need to extend the string, not replace it :)

Comment: Do you want to do this dynamically or just edit the PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Intellij editor or the free Notepad++, you can find and replace by regex.
I'm sure other IDE's have similar functionality

- **Find** `self::([_A-Z]+)_BETWEEN => "(.*)/Date.php"(,)*`
- **Replace** `self::$1_BETWEEN => "$2/Date/Between.php"$3`

The regex groups the variable components of your search together by wrapping it in `()`

In the replace you can reference them in order by `$1`, `$2`, etc..